# Jquery context menu set topmost

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a [Jquery context menu] with [Jquery FullCalendar], my problem is the context menu is showing in back of my event:

**See creenshot:**
http://1drv.ms/1Fa8qKp

Its a calendar of employee DTR.

Here's my JS code:

**CONEXT  MENU JS**

```
   $(function () {
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '.fc-day, .fc-event',
            callback: function (key, options) {
                var m = "clicked: " + key;
                window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
            },
            items: {
                "ApplyLeave": { name: "Apply Leave", icon: "" },
                "ApplyOT": { name: "Apply Overtime", icon: "" },
                "ApplyOB": { name: "Apply Official business", icon: "" },
                "sep1": "---------"
            },
            // TO MAKE CONTEXT TOPMOST
            beforeOpen: function (event, ui) {
                ui.menu.zIndex($(event.target).z);

            }
        });

        $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function (e) {
            console.log('clicked', this);
        })
    });
```

**CALENDAR JS CODE**

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header:{
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title'
            //right: 'month'
        },

        theme: true,

        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: false,
        allDaySlot: true,
        selectable: true,
        events: "/Calendar/GetEventsDTR/",

        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.find('.fc-event-title').append(event.timeInTimeOut);


            //element.qtip({
            //    content: event.Note
            //});


        },



        loading: function (bool) {
            if (bool) {
               $('.fc-header-title').hide();
               $('#loadingImg').show();
            }
            else{
               $('#loadingImg').hide();
               $('.fc-header-title').show();
            }
        },


    });
```

Comment: looks fine to me.. http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9vcx5nvw/2/ - what are the versions of libraries you have used

Comment: ^  Im using nuget package Jquery.FullCalendar with asp MVC 5 the version is 1.6.4, i dint notice the version when i installed it. now i uninstalled the nuget package and manually downloaded the resources from fullcalendar.io and its working perfectly . thanks @ArunPJohny :)